# Are there any dice / casino gambling games / smart contracts for ethereum yet?

Tags: gambling

Are there any dice / casino gambling games / smart contracts for ethereum yet? Where can I get a list of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few gambling Ethereum dapps under development, though not many are production-ready. I'm not aware of an existing comprehensive list like you describe (though [this site](http://dapps.ethercasts.com/) has a good list of dapps in general, some of which are gambling games), but here are the ones I'm aware of:

- [Pokereum](http://www.pokereum.io/) - Poker (crowdfunding soon, mostly in private repo)
- [Powerball](https://github.com/PeterBorah/ethereum-powerball) - Powerball (open-source, not planned for production)
- [Ether Faucet](http://ethfaucet.gratis/) - Lottery (technically; not very gamified)
- [Etherdice](https://etherdice.io/) - Dice game (open-source)
- [vDice](https://www.vdice.io/) - On-Chain Betting (open-source).

Answer (score 4):

There are currently 2:

[etheroll.com](http://etheroll.com) (live)

- random number is generated entirely on blockchain

etherdice.io (shutdown until further notice)

- random number uses 3rd parties

You can view the full list of available smart-contracts here:
http://dapps.ethercasts.com/

Answer (score 0):

We're working on a peer-to-peer implementation using Ethereum as a backbone. Card handling is pretty traditional Mental Poker p2p.

Answer (score 0):

I especially liked dice2.win, and eth.casino.

Currently, We are working on Eth based gambling game, with state-of-art protocol...